# CSS overflow hidden not stop scrolling in safari

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, overflow

overflow: hidden on body tag not disable scrolling on page in safari.
It works in chrome bot not work in safari.
I can't find any solution?

Comment: Hey man, maybe insert some of your code so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

On Safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7)
It is working fine like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    } 
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<p>Lorem...</p>
</body>
</html>
```